# Java: Can I fall through only one case in a switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

In Java, can I fall through only one of the cases in a `switch` statement? I understand that if I `break`, I will fall through to the end of the `switch` statement.

Here's what I mean. Given the following code, on case 2, I want to execute case 2 and case 1. On case 3, I want to execute case 3 and case 1, but not case 2.

```
switch(option) {
    case 3:  // code
             // skip the next case, not break
    case 2:  // code
    case 1:  // code
}
```

Comment: just try giving different orders to switch statements and applying break and without break statement and see what happens

Comment: interesting thought, but it sort of smells of `goto`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, what you are after is not possible with a `switch` statement.  You will fall through each `case` until you hit a `break`.  Perhaps you want `case 1` to be outside of your `switch` statement, so that it is executed regardless.

Comment: Using fall-through is appropriate where each case's behaviors always contain all behaviors of subsequent cases. Method calls + `break` statements are appropriate if each case's actions are different subsets of some behavior pool.

Answer (score 12):

Put the code into methods and call as appropriate. Following your example:

```
void case1() {
    // Whatever case 1 does
}

void case2() {
    // Whatever case 2 does
}

void case3() {
    // Whatever case 3 does
}

switch(option) {
    case 3:
        case3();
        case1();
        break;
    case 2:
        case2();
        case1();
        break;
    case 1: 
        case1();   // You didn't specify what to do for case 1, so I assume you want case1()
        break;
    default:
        // Always a good idea to have a default, just in case demons are summoned
}
```

Of course `case3()`, `case2()`... are very poor method names, you should rename to something more meaningful about what the method actually does.

Comment: This is definitely what he ought to be doing, given the desired result (and desire to use `switch`).

Answer (score 11):

My suggestion is to not use fallthrough for **anything** except cases like the following:

```
switch (option) {
    case 3:
        doSomething();
        break;
    case 2:
    case 1:
        doSomeOtherThing();
        break;
    case 0:
        // do nothing
        break;
}
```

That is, giving several cases the **exact** same block of code to handle them (by "stacking" the `case` labels), making it more or less obvious what the flow is here. I doubt most programmers intuitively check for case fall through (because the indentation makes a case look like as a proper block) or can efficiently read code that relies on it - I know I don't.

Answer (score 1):

```
switch(option) 
{
    case 3:
        ...
        break;
    case 2: 
        ...
        break;
}

... // code for case 1
```

Comment: Copy of nicholas.hauschild's answer.

Comment: @m0skit0 Seeing as nicholas' answer doesn't provide code, this one adds information to the "thread" as a whole. I don't see anything wrong with taking part in a landgrab on SO, it's not a wiki, and you're allowed to improve on others' answers. Merit should be more important than some vague notion of "fairness", and voting generally favours people who post answers sooner, late substantially identical copies are likely to end up buried anyway. (As is the case here.)

Answer (score 0):

You can custom the condition if you want to split cases

```
const { type, data } = valueNotifications

    let convertType = ''
    if (data?.type === 'LIVESTREAM' && type === 'NORMAL') { 
      convertType = 'LIVESTREAM1' 
    } else convertType = type 

    switch (convertType)
```

My use case has split the type from value notifications, but I have a specific LiveStream case which only shows in data.type is 'LIVESTREAM'

Answer (score -1):

Something like this maybe.

```
switch(option) {
    case 3:  // code
             // skip the next case, not break
        // BLOCK-3
    case 2:  // code
        if(option == 3) break;
        // BLOCK-2
    case 1:  // code
        // BLOCK-1
}
```

Comment: `case 2: if(option == 3) break;` You're summoning demons!

Answer (score -2):

In switch statement if you don't `break` the subsequent case is executed. To give you simple example

```
    int value = 2;
    switch(value) {
    case 1: 
        System.out.println("one");
        break;
    case 2: 
        System.out.println("two");
    case 3: 
        System.out.println("three");
        break;
    }
```

Will output

```
two
three
```

Because `break` wansn't executed on case 2

Comment: From the question: *"On case 3, I want to execute case 3 and case 1"*

Comment: This was meant to be a simple example on how switch statements work. Not a direct answer. We don't want a copy & paste answer on SO all the time right?

Comment: But we definitely do want an answer to **the** question :)